# HtmlUnit CookieManager not sending cookies with the first request

Tags: java, cookies, webclient, htmlunit

I am trying to simulate a scenario using HtmlUnit 2.15 where cookies would have been saved in a previous session and should be send to the server when a page is requested in a new session.
Here is the code for that...

```
    String url = "http://localhost:55545/";
    String domain = "localhost:55545";

    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
    CookieManager cookieManager = webClient.getCookieManager();
    cookieManager.setCookiesEnabled(true);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(domain, "cName", "cValue", "/", cal.getTime(), false);

    cookieManager.addCookie(cookie);
    webClient.setCookieManager(cookieManager);

    HtmlPage page = null;
    try {
        page = webClient.getPage(url);
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
        System.err.print(e.toString());
        return;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.err.print(e.toString());
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print(e.toString());
        return;
    }
```

The expected behavior is I should be receiving the cookie "cName" at the server however no cookies are received there. Also verifying the request through a proxy (fiddler) I see that no Cookie header is being sent by the webclient at the first request.

Has anyone been through this? hoping for some advice before I get into debugging HtmlUnit library.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy_for_cookies 
port in domain (host name) is not considered while limiting the scope of a cookie. 
Removing the port from the domain did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36155793/2039709) (basically build the *WebRequest* yourself, add the Cookies manually and then pass it over to *WebClient*), as it could be that your setup (e.g. using Spring Test / WebMVC with HtmlUnit) does not "pass" Cookies from one request to the next.