# How can I add cookies to HtmlUnit request header?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to access a site and I'm having trouble adding the "Cookie" collected to outgoing POST request header. I've been able to verify that they are present in the CookieManager.

Any alternative means to HtmlUnit would also be appreciated.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // Turn off logging to prevent polluting the output.
        Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);

        try {
            final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);



            webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);


            CookieManager cookieManager = webClient.getCookieManager();

            out.println(cookieManager.getCookies().toString());

            out.println("start");

            final HtmlPage loginPage = webClient.getPage("my_url");


            Map<?, ?> additionalRequest1 = loginPage.getWebResponse().getWebRequest().getAdditionalHeaders();

            Iterator<?> ite0 = additionalRequest1.entrySet().iterator();
             while(ite0.hasNext()){
                 out.println(ite0.next());
             }
             out.println("\n");

            out.println("after loginPage");



            out.println(cookieManager.getCookies().toString());

            Set<Cookie> cookies = new HashSet<Cookie>();
            cookies.addAll(webClient.getCookieManager().getCookies());
            StringBuilder cookieHeader = new StringBuilder();

            Iterator<Cookie> ite = cookies.iterator();
            while (ite.hasNext()){
                Cookie cookie = ite.next();
                cookie.getDomain().substring(1);
                String name = cookie.getName();
                String value = cookie.getValue();

                System.out.println("Cookie:" + name + "=" +value);
                webClient.addRequestHeader(name, value);
            }


            final HtmlTextInput login = (HtmlTextInput) loginPage.getElementById("login");
            login.setValueAttribute(USER_EMAIL);

            final HtmlPasswordInput password = (HtmlPasswordInput) loginPage.getElementById("password");
            password.setValueAttribute(USER_PASS);


            final HtmlSubmitInput button_submit = loginPage.getElementByName("login_submit");

            final HtmlPage accessGrantingPage = button_submit.click();
            final HtmlForm  requestForm = (HtmlForm)accessGrantingPage.getElementById("consent_form");

            Map<?, ?> additionalRequest = accessGrantingPage.getWebResponse().getWebRequest().getAdditionalHeaders();

            Iterator<?> ite2 = additionalRequest.entrySet().iterator();
             while(ite2.hasNext()){
                 out.println(ite2.next());
             }
             out.println("\n");

            out.println("after accessGrantingPage");

            out.println(cookieManager.getCookies().toString());
            final HtmlButton consent_accept_button = accessGrantingPage.getElementByName("consent_accept");

            try {
                final HtmlPage authorizationPage = consent_accept_button.click();
                out.println("after authorizationPage");
                out.println(authorizationPage.getUrl().toString());
                out.println(authorizationPage.getWebResponse().getStatusMessage());

                out.println(authorizationPage.getWebResponse().getResponseHeaders());

            } catch (RuntimeException re){
                re.printStackTrace();
            }
            webClient.closeAllWindows();
        } catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }  

    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found out that I can add the header by using setadditionalHeader() from WebClient.

```
        for (int index = 0; index < boxCookies.size(); index++){
            String cookie = boxCookies.toArray()[index].toString();
            String cookieNameValue =cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(";"));
            String name = cookieNameValue.substring(0, cookieNameValue.indexOf("="));
            String value = cookieNameValue.substring(cookieNameValue.indexOf("=") + 1);

            if (index == 0){
                cookieHeader.append(name + "=" +value);
            } else {
                cookieHeader.append("; "+ name + "=" +value);
            }

        }
        WebRequest secondLoginPage = new WebRequest(AUTHORIZE_URL);
        secondLoginPage.setAdditionalHeader("Cookie", cookieHeader.toString());
        HtmlPage loginPage2 = webClient.getPage(secondLoginPage);
```